# How to generate unique id from oracle corda service

Tags: corda

I have a corda state say Employee and I need to generate the Employee Id.
Anyone please let me know how to generate this through corda oracle services?

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle could have an atomic counter that is incremented each time an employee ID is allocated.

Where should you put this counter?

- You can't put it inside a flow, as flows are short-lived and do not share state
- Instead, you need to put the counter inside a service. A Corda service is a long-lived object that is instantiated when a node starts, and allows state to be shared between flows

You could define the service as follows:

```
@CordaService
class Oracle(val services: ServiceHub) : SingletonSerializeAsToken() {
    private val counter = AtomicInteger(0)

    val employeeId
        get() = counter.getAndIncrement()
}
```

And you would retrieve the employee ID in a flow using:

```
serviceHub.cordaService(Oracle::class.java).employeeId
```

Comment: yeah...this is working fine. But if I restart the node the sequence is setting to initial value. Is there any other approach? @Joel